# Does this number theory exercise require $a$ and $b$ to be relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The exercise is

> Let $a \geq 1$ and $b \geq 1$ be integers. Show that there exist integers $u \geq 1$ and $v \geq 1$ such that $u \mid a$ and $v \mid b$, $\gcd(u,v)=1$, and $\text{lcm}(u,v)=ab$.

We have $\gcd(u, v) =1$ so $u$ and $v$ are relatively prime, and $u \mid a$ and $v \mid b$ so $u$ and $v$ must be divisors of $a$ and $b$ with prime factors belonging *exclusively* to $a$ and $b$.
From the fact that $\gcd(u,v) \text{lcm}(u,v) = uv$ it follows that $uv=ab$ so the product of two relatively prime numbers must be $ab$. But what if $a$ and $b$ share a factor greater than $1$?

For example, say that $a=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ and $b= 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$. If we must find a $u$ and $v$ satisfying the conditions above. We have $uv = ab = 3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 = 169575$. So to choose a $u$ and $v$ such that $u \mid a$, $v \mid b$ and $uv=ab$ we can simply let $u=a$ and $v=b$. But $\gcd(u,v) = \gcd(a,b) = 5$. That obviously won't work. Ok, what if we group the fives into one of them so $\gcd(u,v)=1$, let's say $u$? Then $u \nmid a$. And so on.

It seems like it's impossible to choose such a $u$ and $v$ unless $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Is this a mistake or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah, probably the theorem is supposed to be $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b).$ You are correct, it is not true if $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1.$

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: The formulation of the theorem is fine. There is no need to assume that a and b are relatively prime.

Comment: @BrianMoehring exercise 34 of section 1.3 in "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by W. Keith Nicholson. I've found a lot of errors in this book (I've only been reading it for a few days now), the author has even made some simply arithmetic errors.

Comment: Yes, I read the exercise in a wrong way. I didn't see what was on the paper/screen; I couldn't help to *see* the true conclusion $$ u\cdot v = \text{lcm}(a\ b)$$.

Comment: $ab = \color{#c00}{{\rm lcm}(u,v) = uv}\iff (a/u)(b/v)=1\iff u=a,\, v = b,\,$ by $(\color{#c00}{u,v)=1},$ so $\,(a,b)=1$

Comment: Almost surely there is a typo and the correct conclusion should be $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = uv,\,$ which is a very common exercise, e.g. see the linked dupe (and its links), both in lcm form and [dual gcd form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085179/242).

Comment: As such you should instead accept wlod's answer (or, better, delete the question since it is based on a typo so has little value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thomas Andrews' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748254/does-this-number-theory-exercise-require-a-and-b-to-be-relatively-prime#comment10075013_4748254) is correct, re: it's not true if $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$. One relatively easy way to see this is, since we're dealing with only positive integers, then $u \mid a \;\to\; u \le a$ and $v \mid b \;\to\; v \le b$, so $uv \le ab$, with equality *only* if $u=a$ and $v=b$. However, then $\gcd(u,v)=1 \;\to\; \gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Thus, the current problem statement is incorrect. One possible way to fix it is to add the requirement that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then we can just choose $u=a$ and $v=b$ since $uv = ab$ in that case.

Another way to adjust the statement is to do as Thomas's comment suggested, i.e., change $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v)=ab$ to $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ instead (or, since $\operatorname{lcm}(u,v)=uv$, we get the suggestion in [Wlod AA's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4748259)). Then with $p_i$, for $1 \le i \le n$, being the $n$ primes dividing $a$ and/or $b$, we get

$$a = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{q_i}, \;\; b = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{r_i}$$

We can have $u$ be the product of all $p_i^{q_i}$ where $q_i \ge r_i$, and $v$ be the product of all the $p_i^{r_i}$ where $r_i \gt q_i$. Then $\gcd(u,v)=1$, plus also

$$\operatorname{lcm}(u,v) = uv = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{\max(q_i,r_i)} = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$$

Comment: Almost surely the intended form is not what you wrote but instead that in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

The correct conclusion should be:

$$ u\cdot v\ =\ \text{lcm}(a\,\ b) $$

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is a very common exercise and surely what was intended, i.e. it is a **misprint**.